# Cannot convert return expression type to return type with closure?

Tags: swift, closures

Hello i have some func for pagination messages.

```
   class func listMessages() -> (Int, Int, ([ChatItemProtocol]) -> Void) {
    let service = MessageService()
    func list(count: Int, offset: Int, comp:([ChatItemProtocol]) -> Void) {
        let params : [String : AnyObject] = ["offset" : offset, "limit" : count]
        service.listMessagesForRoom(params) { (messages) in
            comp(messages.map({$0}))
        }
    }
    return list
}
```

and i have some error :

```
Cannot convert return expression of type '(Int, offset: Int, comp: ([ChatItemProtocol]) -> Void) -> ()' to return type '(Int, Int, ([ChatItemProtocol]) -> Void)' (aka '(Int, Int, Array<ChatItemProtocol> -> ())')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`listMessages(...)` expects the following tuple return type

```
(Int, Int, ([ChatItemProtocol]) -> Void)
```

The function `list(...)`, on the other hand, uses the above as argument but will implicitly also contain a `Void` (/empty tuple type `()`) return type. I.e., the full signature for `list(...)` is

```
(Int, Int, ([ChatItemProtocol]) -> Void) -> ()
```

leading to a type mis-match when you attempt to return `list` as the return value of `listMessages(...)`.

Without knowing the purpose of your code, it is difficult to give any concrete advice, but you could fix the above by modifying the return type of `listMessages(...)` to include also the `()` return type, in so matching the signature of `list(...)`

```
class func listMessages() -> ((Int, Int, ([ChatItemProtocol]) -> Void) -> ())
```

Comment: Ok, i am using library Сhatto for chat, there is class name SlidindDataSource which  test app in repository chatto in github and using for pagination in chat. It work with test data, but i want load messages from server. So i trying write my own messages generator which will run asynchronously. Thanks for the help. This is class in which generate test messages [chatto](https://github.com/badoo/Chatto/blob/master/ChattoApp/ChattoApp/SlidingDatasSource.swift)

Comment: @nickheck this is beyond the scope of your question, and sounds like a question of design rather than one of syntax. Possibly consider asking a new question regarding how to achieve (design-wise) this. Make sure to include all necssary details in the question itself, rather than by links (while still keeping the information somewhat minimal).